# If/Then in Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

In very simple terms I want to assign a string to a variable in a certain circumstance.  I've tried to put the if then statement on the outside of the linq statement in a global variable but then it runs through the if/then assigns the string to variable and then prints it out for each row in my excel file that is being produced.

So how do i put a statement similar to this

```
var status = "";
if(_db.Owners.Select(i => i.Item1) != null && _db.Owners.Select(i => i.Item2) == null)
            {
                status = "S";
            }
```

to my linq statement that looks similar to this

```
return _db.Owners
    .Select(owner => new
        {
            CustomerId = owner.Report.CustomerId,
            IdType = status,//I want this statement to print that status S only where the statement is true
        }
```

Comment: you only want items with status = S in the returned collection or you only want it to *print* in that case?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right - you want only the `owner` objects with `Item1 != null` and `Item2 == null` to be printed with status S? What about other records - what status would they have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `IdType` is a string, which you want empty if the statement is false. In that case, you can use this:

```
return _db.Owners
     .Select(owner => new
         {
             CustomerId = owner.Report.CustomerId,
             IdType = (owner.Item1 != null && owner.Item2 == null) ? "S": string.Empty, 
    }
```

**UPDATE**
If you want to add a second case, you can do this:

```
return _db.Owners
     .Select(owner => new
         {
             CustomerId = owner.Report.CustomerId,
             IdType = (owner.Item1 != null && owner.Item2 == null) 
                     ? "S" : ([second case condition] ? [value] : string.Empty), 
    }
```

Comment: If I wanted to add a second case would I write that after the : ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use the (infamous) ternary operator `?`

```
new {
   CustomerId = owner.Report.CustomerId,
   IdType = yourTestExpressionFromTheIfAbove ? "S" : string.Empty
}
```

Is that what you're asking? Do you just want to inline the expression and remove the external (temporary) variable?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
return _db.Owners
    .Select(owner => new
    {
        CustomerId = owner.Report.CustomerId,
        IdType = owner.Item1 != null && owner.Item2 == null ? "S" : [your other value]
    })
    .ToList();
```

Where [your other value] is whatever status you want if the record does not satisfy your condition.